# How to transfer a file from one android emulator to my Android device?

Tags: java, android, networking

I want to develop one small application to transfer a file from my android emulator to an android device through coding. I dont know how to achieve this, please if anybody knows help me.

Answer (score 1):

Learn how the [communication](http://www.davidreilly.com/java/java_network_programming/) is done via Java. Then implement client and server applications and install them to emulator and to the phone.